# Merge Conflict: Collect relevant commits from conflicting files

Tags: git

Given a conflicting merge,

1. Collect the list of files that conflicted
2. Determine the related commits from this list of files

Example:

```
MERGE Conflict!
 |\
 | \
 |  \
 A  B
 | /
 |/
 C
 |
 |
```

Commits on both B and A have changed foo.txt, creating a conflict.

When B is merged into A, I want all the commits in A or B but before C that changed foo.txt

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding your problem correctly, you're looking for all commits that affected a given file **before** the branches diverged:

You'll want to start by figuring out where the two branches have diverged:

```
git merge-base A B
```

This should get you the hash of commit C.

To get a list of unmerged files:

```
git diff --name-only --diff-filter=U
```

You can then do:

```
git log <hash of C> -- <file path>
```

for each unmerged file to find a list of commits, up to and including commit C, that have affected that file.

Answer (score 1):

Given your above history, this:

```
git log A B ^C -- foo.txt
```

will show you all commits in either the `A` or `B` branch that changed the file `foo.txt` (I'm assuming you actually want the commits *after* `C`, not *before* it - but if you want the commits before `C`, you can just do `git log C -- foo.txt`). If you don't actually know the hash for `C`, you can use `git merge-branch A B` to determine it. If you want to see the actual changes made in each commit, rather than just the list of commits, then use `git log -p ...`.